# I'm getting an exception in particular part of code

Tags: c++, class, oop, exception, operator-keyword

I'm getting an exception with pointers while compiling overloaded operator. The exception says "Exception thrown: write access violation.
TempString.Pointer was 0x1110112." I'm expecting the operator to combine two custom strings into one.

Overloaded operator:

```
MyString MyString::operator+(MyString &String) {
    MyString TempString;
    TempString.StringLength = this->StringLength + String.StringLength;
for (int i = 0; i < this->StringLength + String.StringLength - 1; i++) {
    if (i < this->StringLength) {
        TempString.Pointer[i] = this->Pointer[i]; // Exception pops up here
    }
    else {
        TempString.Pointer[i] = String.Pointer[i];
    }
}
return TempString;
};
```

Constructors:

```
MyString::MyString() {
    StringLength = 0;
    Pointer = nullptr;
}

MyString::MyString(char* String) {
    Pointer = String;
    for (int i = 0; Pointer[i]; i++) {
        StringLength++;
    }
}
```

Main.cpp:

```
#include "MyString.h"
#include <iostream>

int main() {

    char String1[] = "abcdef";
    MyString NewString(String1);

    char String2[] = "cdefa";
    MyString SubString(String2);

    MyString BrandNewString(NewString + SubString);
    cout << BrandNewString.GetStringLength() << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `Pointer = String;` is very very very dangerous. When you "null" it (or its class dies) if the same pointer is stored in other class it becomes invalid. Use a [std::shared_ptr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) instead.

Comment: You're not handling allocation and deallocation. You have issues with pointer ownership. Encapsulation will be important to make those possible.

Comment: please show a [mre]

Comment: That also doesn't look like the normal signature for operator+. You have too many concepts in play for your level. You should be following a text book.

Answer (score 0):

The line:

```
TempString.StringLength = this->StringLength + String.StringLength;
```

does not allocate the memory for your string. 
You need to allocate the memory before writing to it (in line `TempString.Pointer[i] = this->Pointer[i]`).

Can you show your constructor content ?

What you have written is a read-only string class. It's attached to an external char array.

It's unfortunate but you can't mutate those. Notice that you could modify the content of the external char array but not the size. 
To make a concatenation (like in `abc`+`def`) you need to create an array that's as large as the sum of the length of both initial array, but you don't have such array anywhere in your code.

So you need to create them first (it's called an allocation, usually with `operator new`, can be with `malloc`), but then, your class will have no way to know if the array it's pointing to is allocated by itself or comes from anywhere else. Thus, your class will not be able to deallocate the array.

So, you should choose what scenario you want your class to perform:

1. Stay a read only class (you will not be able to perform a concatenation or any operation that's changing the array size).
2. Become a true string class (you'll have to allocate an char array in the constructor and deallocate it in the destructor) and then copy the received string in your own managed array. While you'll be writing such a class, you should have a look at the `std::string` class, which is now doing that.

What you should have, logically in an concatenating operator:

```
MyString MyString::operator+(const MyString & o) const {
   MyString ret(length + o.length);
   for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
       ret.pointer[i] = pointer[i];
   for(int i = 0; i < o.length; i++)
       ret.pointer[i+length] = o.pointer[i];
   return ret;
}

MyString::MyString(int length) 
: length(length), pointer(new char[length+1]) 
{
  pointer[length] = 0;
}

MyString::~MyString() { delete[] pointer; pointer = nullptr; length = 0; }

MyString::MyString(const char * str)
: length(strlen(str)), pointer(new char[length+1])
{
    memcpy(pointer, str, length+1);
}
```

Comment: Both constuctors are shown above. Or am I getting it wrong?